# Stop flushing the last command when hitting enter

Tags: vimscript, neovim, command-line, command

Suppose I wrote this command:

```
command! -nargs=1 E echo ' -> <args>'
```

and when user feeds an argument,

```
:E abc
```

I intend to see the following effect as they hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
:E abc -> abc
```

Of course that's not happening, since vim flushes `:E abc` when printing  `-> abc`, leaving the command-line showing:

```
 -> abc
```

Is there an option to retain the command typed by user in the command-line, before finishing execution? Or are there alternative ways to achieve the same effect?

Comment: See `:help c_CTRL-\_e`.

Comment: Since you're defining the command yourself, you can simply prepend "E <args>" to " -> <args>", can't you?

Comment: @3N4N could solve this problem to some extent, but what I really want is to retain the command *as exactly typed by the user*, where basically every white space matters.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution with functionality of command `E` being moved entirely to another function `F` to be called inside command-line expression prompt, thanks to [romainl's hint](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39629/stop-flushing-the-last-command-when-hitting-enter#comment72414_39629):

```
command! -nargs=1 E

cnoremap <CR> <C-\>eF()<CR><CR>

" call me only in c_<C-\>e mode
function! F()
    let cmd = ':' .. getcmdline()
    let parse = v:lua.vim.api.nvim_parse_cmd(cmd, {})
    let cmdname = parse.cmd
    if cmdname ==# 'E' && len(parse.args) > 0
        let arg = parse.args[0]
        return 'echo ''' .. cmd .. ' -> ' .. arg .. ''''
    else 
        return cmd
    endif
endfunction
```

While this solution parses command string utilising nvim API, vim users may need to come up with some other ways to parse command; I cannot think of any builtin functions with the same effect.